# How to change an image source when the viewport pass an #id [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

How to change an image source when the viewport pass an #id, with Javascript ?

The link below is a picture of what i would like to do.

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR2a0.jpg)

I don't know how to bind a scrollEvent to a div. It's been a long time since I coded in Javascript...

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: You need to show some sort of effort at attempting your issue. Please provide some code with your question that attempts to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) does the job quite well:

```js
observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((e) => {
    if (e.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      document.querySelector(`div[data-id=${e.target.id}]`).classList.add('active');
    } else {
      document.querySelector(`div[data-id=${e.target.id}]`).classList.remove('active');
    }
  })
})
document.querySelectorAll('div[id]').forEach((e) => {
  observer.observe(e);
})
```

```css
div[id] {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.menu div {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #54DF6E !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="id-1">

</div>
<div id="id-2">

</div>
<div id="id-3">

</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div data-id="id-1"></div>
  <div data-id="id-2"></div>
  <div data-id="id-3"></div>
</div>
```